# How to fetch python output and get to dynamic massive

Tags: python, jenkins, out, massive

I have got Jenkins and python, and some jobs in a queue. I have got a script whic

```
import jenkins 
j = jenkins.Jenkins('http:///', '....', '.......')
queue_info = j.get_queue_info()
print(queue_info)
```

This command give me the following output:

```
[{u'task': {u'url': u'http://', u'color': u'aborted', u'name': u'f1111111111'}, u'stuck': False, u'url': 
u'queue/item/37/', u'inQueueSince': 1397554800875L, u'actions': [{u'causes': [{u'userName': u'admin', u'userId': u'admin', u'shortDescription':
u'Started by user admin'}]}], u'why': u'Waiting for next available executor on NO_1', u'buildable': True, u'params': u'', u'buildableStartMilliseconds': 1397554800878L, u'id': 37, u'pending': False, u'blocked': False}
```

How to fetch the name of u'name' and get it to dynamic massive in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is a list of dictionaries, so you can simply access the first entry in the list and use the dictionary's keys.

Let's start by defining a function here:

```
import subprocess as sp

''' Runs a program '''
def run(prog):
      print("Lets run program %s" % prog)
      sp.Popen([prog], stdout=sp.STDOUT, stderr=sp.STDOUT)

      # This makes the script wait until the end of the program
      sp.wait()
```

Then, in the for loop, you just need to call the run function:

```
for n in queue_info:
      run(n['task']['name'])
```

Comment: I have to use this name because i need to run virtual machine for this queue, so i think that it will be a good idea to make an massive like job_name1 = 1, job_name2 = 2,and run the machine for the 1,2,3..... and so on

Comment: and how can get param to my output? i mean this [0], if i have a lot of jobs?

Comment: You can simply use a for loop to iterate over the array. Just edited my answer, check it out.

Comment: Sorry, i'am new in python, i made like you told.
queue_info = j.get_queue_info()
print(queue_info)
for n in queue_info:
      print queue_info[n]['task']['name']
and have the following 
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict

Comment: Thanks it work's. Maybe you can tell me how can i made this scenario: for each [n] , invoke program(Maestro) and exec smth...

Comment: Just updated the answer. Basically, you need to define a function that uses subprocess to launch the program and invoke it from the for loop. If you want to pass some parameters to it, you'll need to first extract them from your queue_info and then pass them to the run function.